# Blackberry Playbook App Debug Installation Error

Tags: blackberry-playbook

I am trying to install a Blackberry Webworks App from my MAC onto a playbook using a usb cable and terminal line commands blackberry-deploy -installApp...

I am getting an error referring to an author mismatch between application and debug token

result::failure 881 application author does not match debug token author

has anyone had the same issue?

thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the following properties in your bar-descriptor.xml file

```
   <!--  Name of author which is used for signing. 
         Must match the developer name of your development certificate -->
   <author>**</author>

   <!--  Unique author ID assigned by signing authority. Required if using debug tokens -->
   <authorId>**</authorId>
```

Comment: Thanks Smugrik, i have just got the same problem again, but this time it is adding a new debug token to the same device. Do you know if there is a method to check all debug token references have been removed from the device before adding a new one. cheers!

Comment: swipe-down the PlayBook menu go to Security -> Development mode, on the screen, you can see informations on the Debug Token loaded on the PlayBook, and you can remove it clicking the "Remove Debug Token" button. There is only one debug token at a time on the PlayBook, loading a new one erases the previous one

Answer (score 0):

"I had similar issue. Check that  in blackbery-tablet.xml  and   fields are correct.

To get the right values for those fields just rename your packed .bar file to .zip, then unarchieve it. There will be manifest.mf file in META-INF folder. Open it with notepad. Grab  and   values from there and rebuild your app.
If that does not help, then rebuild debug token and make sure you install it on the device. Debug token needs to have correct device pin.

Please click the Thumbs Up icon if this comment has helped you! If your issue is resolved, please click the solution button on the resolution!" - source : http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Failure-881-Application-Author-does-not-match-debug-token-author/m-p/2055935#M32567

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. and it was not an "author" problem : I was trying to deploy in debug mode and the debugToken was just not installed on the device.

The debugToken must be on the device so that the deploy can work. You can upload the debugToken with :

```
blackberry-deploy -installDebugToken debugtoken.bar -device 169.254.0.1 -password
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Open the bar file with WinRar BUT DO NOT EXTRACT. Doing so will corrupt the META file. Within the WinRar Application locate the META.INF file and double click to open. (if the file type is not set to open with Notepad automatically choose it as the preferred application to do so.)

In the open Notepad with the META info, change the author name and author ID to that of your existing debugtoken. (This can be accessed from the debugtoken via the same process to locate the desired application's META.INF).

Close Notepad and choose to save upon exit. WinRar SHOULD ask if you would like to save it to the archive. Simply choose yes, then exit and attempt the installation again with the newly edited application bar file.

I observed that using this method, there is no change in the size of the originally packed file and supposedly no damage to its original contents.

Answer (score 0):

Open with a text editor the file `blackberry-tablet.xml`, the file is inside your `<BlackBerry WebWorks SDK Tablet install folder>\bbwp\AirAppTemplates\src\`.

You should see a section with something like:

```
<publisher>Sample Inc.</publisher>
<category>core.internet</category>
```

after this section you have to add

```
<author>*replace with your author name info*</author>
<authorId>*replace with your author id info*</authorId>
```

You'll have to get your author and your author id info from the debug token that you uploaded on your PlayBook. You should have your debug token on your computer, rename .bar to .zip and extract. With a text editor look in the META-INF folder at the MANIFEST.MF file for values for `Package-Author:` and `Package-Author-Id:` folowed by the actual string values.

Hope this helps.